# Entity framework ado.net entity data model no muestra mi servidor SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

Tengo un proyecto consola al cual le agrego un nuevo elemento, ahi elijo ado.net entity data model, una vez hecho esto elijo -> EF designer desde la base de datos -> siguiente -> nueva conexion -> microsodt sql server -> continuar -> ahora donde dice nombre del servidor le doy en la pestaña para que muestre mi servidor y no aparece, alguien sabe cual es el problema o que me falta configurar?

NOTA: Aunque ingrese los datos manualmente no lo toma.

Comment: Donde le pones el nombre del servidor para que luego en el combobox te muestra las base de datos. Pone el nombre completo del sqlserver, para no errarle podes copiar desde el sqlmanagement cuando te conectas al motor de la base.

Comment: aunque lo agregue manualmente no lo toma

Comment: Y esta prendido tu servidor?

Comment: Si entras por sql management te muestra normal el servidor? No recuerdo de memoria pero quizas te esta faltando algun permiso de configurar

Comment: Si sirvio muchas gracias, lo intente una vez mas y no se que habre pasado por alto, pero sirvio, muchas gracias de nuevo.